# How to add CC with Lotus Notes email in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, email, excel

I have a macro which sends an email to recipients automatically from Excel VBA, I have different columns in my Excel file such as "recipient email address" and "cc", my macro will retrieve data from worksheet and then format accordingly. Now I need to add a "CC" field with two email addresses to my email format and I couldn't figure out how to do that, can anyone help me with that?

Here's how my worksheet looks like:
[image]

Here's the entire code for macro:

```
Sub Send_Unformatted_Rangedata(i As Integer)
Dim noSession As Object, noDatabase As Object, noDocument As Object
Dim vaRecipient As Variant

Dim rnBody As Range
Dim Data As DataObject
Dim rngGen As Range
Dim rngApp As Range
Dim rngspc As Range

y:

Dim stSubject As String
stSubject = "Change Request " + (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AA").Value) + (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AB").Value) + (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AC").Value) + (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AD").Value) + (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AE").Value) + (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AF").Value) + (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AG").Value) + (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AH").Value) + (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AI").Value)
'Const stMsg As String = "Data as part of the e-mail's body."
'Const stPrompt As String = "Please select the range:"

'This is one technique to send an e-mail to many recipients but for larger
'number of recipients it's more convenient to read the recipient-list from
'a range in the workbook.
vaRecipient = VBA.Array(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "U").Value, Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "V").Value)

On Error Resume Next
'Set rnBody = Application.InputBox(Prompt:=stPrompt, _
     Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
'The user canceled the operation.
'If rnBody Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Set rngGen = Nothing
'Set rngApp = Nothing
'Set rngspc = Nothing

Set rngGen = Sheets("General Overview").Range("A1:C30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'Set rngApp = Sheets("Application").Range("A1:E13").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

'Set rngspc = Sheets(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "P").Value).Range(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "Q").Value).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'Set rngspc = Union(rngspc, Sheets(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "P").Value).Range(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "R").Value).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

On Error GoTo 0

If rngGen Is Nothing And rngApp Is Nothing And rngspc Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
           vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If


'Instantiate Lotus Notes COM's objects.
Set noSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Set noDatabase = noSession.GETDATABASE("", "")

'Make sure Lotus Notes is open and available.
If noDatabase.IsOpen = False Then noDatabase.OPENMAIL

'Create the document for the e-mail.
Set noDocument = noDatabase.CreateDocument

'Copy the selected range into memory.
'The clipboard will get replaced by the multiple copies.
'rngApp.Copy
'rngspc.Copy
rngGen.Copy

'To be able to see the email and manually send it add this below
 'Call oUIDoc.Save(True, False, False)
 'CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace").EDITDOCUMENT True, oUIDoc
 'AppActivate "> " & oUIDoc.Subject

'Retrieve the data from then copied range.
Set Data = New DataObject
Data.GetFromClipboard

'Add data to the mainproperties of the e-mail's document.
With noDocument
  .Form = "Memo"
  .SendTo = vaRecipient

  .Subject = stSubject
  'Retrieve the data from the clipboard.
  .Body = Data.GetText & " " & stMsg
  .SAVEMESSAGEONSEND = True
End With

'Send the e-mail.
'changed by Xu Ying to make the email being sent from automatically to manually

    Dim uiMemo As Object
    Dim ws As Object
    Set ws = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
    noDocument.Save True, True, False
    Set uiMemo = ws.EDITDOCUMENT(True, noDocument)

'Release objects from memory.
Set noDocument = Nothing
Set noDatabase = Nothing
Set noSession = Nothing


'Activate Excel for the user.

'AppActivate "Excel"

'Empty the clipboard.
Application.CutCopyMode = False

i = i + 1
If Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "U").Value <> "" Then
GoTo y:
End If

MsgBox "The e-mail has successfully been created and distributed.", vbInformation

End Sub

Sub Send_Formatted_Range_Data(i As Integer)
Dim oWorkSpace As Object, oUIDoc As Object
Dim rnBody As Range
Dim lnRetVal As Long
Dim stTo As String

Dim stSubject As String
Const stMsg As String = "An e-mail has been succesfully created and saved."

Dim rngGen As Range
Dim rngApp As Range
Dim rngspc As Range

stTo = Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "U").Value

stSubject = "E-Mail For Approval for " + (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "A").Value) + "  for the Project  " + Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xls", "")

'Check if Lotus Notes is open or not.
lnRetVal = FindWindow("NOTES", vbNullString)

If lnRetVal = 0 Then
  MsgBox "Please make sure that Lotus Notes is open!", vbExclamation
  Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rngGen = Sheets("General Overview").Range("A1:C30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set rngApp = Sheets("Application").Range("A1:E13").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Set rngspc = Sheets(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "P").Value).Range(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "Q").Value).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set rngspc = Union(rngspc, Sheets(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "P").Value).Range(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "R").Value).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
On Error GoTo 0

If rngGen Is Nothing And rngApp Is Nothing And rngspc Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
           vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

rngGen.Copy
rngApp.Copy
rngspc.Copy

'Instantiate the Lotus Notes COM's objects.
Set oWorkSpace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")

On Error Resume Next

Set oUIDoc = oWorkSpace.ComposeDocument("", "mail\xldennis.nsf", "Memo")
On Error GoTo 0

Set oUIDoc = oWorkSpace.CurrentDocument

'Using LotusScript to create the e-mail.
Call oUIDoc.FieldSetText("EnterSendTo", stTo)
Call oUIDoc.FieldSetText("EnterCopyTo", stCC)
Call oUIDoc.FieldSetText("Subject", stSubject)

'The can be used if You want to add a message into the created document.
Call oUIDoc.FieldAppendText("Body", vbNewLine & stBody)

'Here the selected range is pasted into the body of the outgoing e-mail.
Call oUIDoc.GoToField("Body")
Call oUIDoc.Paste

'Save the created document.
Call oUIDoc.Save(True, False, False)
'If the e-mail also should be sent then add the following line.
'Call oUIDoc.Send(True)

'Release objects from memory.
Set oWorkSpace = Nothing
Set oUIDoc = Nothing

With Application
  .CutCopyMode = False
  .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

MsgBox stMsg, vbInformation

'Activate Lotus Notes.
AppActivate ("Notes")
'Last edited Feb 11, 2015 by Peter Moncera

End Sub
```

Comment: Doing this from memory... `SendTo`,`CopyTo` (This is what you want?) and `BlindCopyTo`

Comment: @SiddharthRout I just want to add some email addresses to the cc field in email, is CopyTo capable of that?

Comment: Like I said, I am doing this from memory. So why not test it? :) I don't have Lotus notes as well...

Comment: Just want to double check with you:) Thanks I'll go test it now:)

Comment: Awesome! I am getting old... Can't trust this memory :P

Comment: I've got an earlier sample on this site if it's of help also: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?228734-Lotus-Notes-R5-Sending-MULTIPLE-Email-using-VB

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way how I solved my own problem with the help from @Siddharth Rout

Firstly, I need to add `Dim vaCC As Variant` and cell position of email addresses for those I need to cc:

```
vaCC = VBA.Array(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AA").Value, Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AB").Value, Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "AC").Value)
```

Then add data to the mainproperties of the e-mail's document:

```
With noDocument
  .CopyTo = vaCC
End With
```

At the last step, set `Dim CopyTo As String`

Hope this will be of any help to those in need.